# Do you know some Ruby api to manipulate EPS files?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, eps

I am making a web app using Rails 3 to make some drawing, but I need to make EPS files.
Do you know some gem or api to create EPS (Encapsulated PostScript) images?

I am not close to use another image format, maybe SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) could be an alternative, but my requirement was using EPS's.

Thank you!

Comment: EPS is inherently complex... what sort of EPS do you mean (vector, pixel... Photoshop, Illustrator...) ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know how complicated your drawings are. I could well imagine you can just do it with erb, and some helper methods. See example files at http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/eps/eps.html (open eps files in text editor)